# Debian 10 fstab - Is there an option to prevent boot sequence hanging when device does not exist?

Tags: debian, mount, fstab, nfsv4

I have a Debian 10 machine which has a `nfs` mountpoint specified in fstab.

This is the line

```
10.0.0.2:/mnt/md0    /mnt/md0    nfs4    _netdev,auto,nofail    0    0
```

I thought `nofail` would prevent my boot sequence hanging for (precicely) 1:32 while a time out takes place while the system is looking for the nfs drive. However this doesn't appear to be the correct opion, as it is not mentioned in my systems man pages. A search suggested `nobootwait` might be an alternative but again this is not mentioned in the man pages. There doesn't appear to be any relevant option, unless I am looking in the wrong document?

Is there any way to specify that the drive should be automatically mounted, when it is present, and only when it is present. Both at boot time, and additionally, if the drive is "somehow seen" later on.

eg; If I boot my workstation, and the drive is not present (server not booted) it should not wait an additional minute and a half to boot.

then; If I boot the server at a later time, is there any way to automatically detect/mount the nfs drive? I *guess* this could be done with some kind of cron script which pings the network address `10.0.0.2`? (My server IP.)

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/419909/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/459731/5132 , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/569818/5132 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For automatically mounting NFS when present, `autofs` can be used ([autofs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autofs))

As mentioned in `man` fstab(5)

**nofail**

> do not report errors for this device if it does not exist.

AFAIK **nobootwait** was only for ubuntu-based distros (which is not a valid option anymore)

You can use `x-systemd.device-timeout=` (more info [systemd.mount](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/systemd.mount.5.en.html))

**x-systemd.device-timeout=**

> Configure how long systemd should wait for a device to show up before
>   giving up on an entry from /etc/fstab. Specify a time in seconds or
>   explicitly append a unit such as "s", "min", "h", "ms".
>
> Note that this option can only be used in /etc/fstab, and will be
>   ignored when part of the Options= setting in a unit file.

The default device timeout is 90 seconds, so a disconnected external device with only `nofail`will make your boot take 90 seconds longer, unless you reconfigure the timeout as shown. Make sure not to set the timeout to `0`, as this translates to **infinite timeout**.

Comment: So I just add to my list of options in `fstab` so it now looks like this `10.0.0.2:/mnt/md0    /mnt/md0    nfs4    _netdev,noauto,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=1000ms    0    0`. Is that right?

Comment: This is fine currently, could you please check and share feedback? I also update the answer.

Comment: No problem I will update you on next boot

Comment: Works as expected